# How to rebind the RadGrid after close the RadWindow

Tags: telerik, radgrid, radwindow

I have a `MasterPage` with the `RadAjaxManager`.

I have a `RadGrid` in my `ContentPage` (`Default.aspx`). 
I would like to rebind the `RadGrid` after closing my `RadWindow`.

How can I rebind the `RadGrid`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your content page (`default.aspx`) when you are calling your RadWindow to open, attach the  property `OnClientClose="refreshGrid"`.  When the window is closed that function will be called.

```
<telerik:RadWindow runat="server" ID="myRadWin" OnClientClose="refreshGrid" />
```

And you can use a function like this to get your radGrid and rebind it clientside.

```
function refreshGrid() 
{        
      var masterTable = $find("<%=radGrid1.clientId%>").get_masterTableView();
      masterTable.rebind();
}
```

---

I've added this in for your case with the masterPages but leaving the above as it's also valid for anyone else stumbling upon this question as there are more than 1 way to accomplish this.

In your Rad Window page include a JavaScript function that you will use to close your RadWindow which will also make a callback to your parent page.  The most elegant approach would be to make a generic call back function that is handled in your MasterPage which includes some arguments, and have that function delegate it to another more specific one for the page you're working on.  A more generic approach is what I've described below:

In your RadWindow Page:

```
function CloseAndRefreshGrid() {
            var oWin = GetRadWindow();
            var parentWindow = oWin.BrowserWindow;
            $(oWin).ready(function()
            {
                oWin.close();
            });
            parentWindow.refreshGrid();            
        }

 function GetRadWindow() {
            var oWindow = null;
            if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow; //Will work in Moz in all cases, including classic dialog
            else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow; //IE (and Moz as well)

            return oWindow;
        }
```

In your content page you can include this JavaScript:

```
 function refreshGrid() 
    {        
          var masterTable = $find("<%=radGrid1.clientId%>").get_masterTableView();
          masterTable.rebind();
    }
```

Comment: I have the RadWindows in the MasterPage and i can't to call the radGrid from MasterPage because RadGrid is in the ContentPage.

Comment: I've added in a different approach for you to try.